# Telling manager I'm not a good fit

Tags: professionalism, internal-transfer

I joined my job 6 months ago and my team is incredibly isolated whereas I'm used to a collaborative, sociable team. I'm really struggling to stay interested and noticed I'm becoming quite depressed at work due to this. I don't mind the work but team is just not the right fit for me.

I know of another team who I fit into very well and have already got word they'd take me in from their manager.

What's the best way to tell my manager I'd like a transfer due to poor team fit? I keep practicing in my head but it doesn't seem to come out professional. Should I have other reasons than this as well?

Answer (score 10):

> What's the best way to tell my manager I'd like a transfer due to poor
>   team fit?

First make sure you have a position on the new team first. Make sure this is a firm commitment and not contingent on your current manager's approval or such. Make sure you understand and follow your company's transfer policy. And of course make sure the new team is one where you'll want to stay more than 6 months.

Then just talk to your manager.

Something like "I really appreciated working on your team. But I've learned that I really need a more collaborative, social work environment than here. So I've decided to transfer to [group x]. I want to make sure the transition is smooth for you and your team, so I'd like to work together to make that happen."

No need to dig in deeper or talk about depression or make up other excuses. No need to be embarrassed. These things happen.